# Make numbers be seen as icons by browser

Tags: html, css

So I've got a little "intro" box that I styled effects for using fontawesome icons. The effect is nice and I would like to keep it, however later down the page I have a "stats" box and I want to use the same style & effect but using normal numbers so that the number can dynamically change via a php script. Of course, whenever I use normal numbers the effect doesn't work because I styled the CSS to work with the fontawesome icons. Is there a way to make the text parse as an icon, or do I need to rewrite my css?

HTML

```
<!-- Statistics -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 centre">
          <h2 class="b-title">Some Statistics</h2><br /><br />
          <!--Section 1-->
          <div class="stats-box stats-box1">
            <div class="text-center block-box">
              <div class="stats-effect-inner"> <a class="stats-effect icon-unlock icon-3x" href="#"></a> </div>
              <h3 style="text-decoration: none;">Domains</h3>
              <p>The number of free domains given.</p>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

Relative CSS is here. Full styling CSS is in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CYEa/).

```
/*------------ Hover Effect Stats ------- */
.stats-effect { display: inline-block; font-size: 0px; cursor: pointer; margin: 15px 30px; width: 90px; height: 90px; -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%; text-align: center; position: relative; z-index: 1; color: #fff; }

.stats-effect:after { pointer-events: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%; content: ''; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; }

.stats-effect:before { speak: none; font-size: 48px; line-height: 90px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; display: block; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }

/* Effect 1 */
.stats-effect-inner .stats-effect { background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); -webkit-transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s; -moz-transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s; transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s; }

.stats-effect-inner .stats-effect:after { top: -7px; left: -7px; padding: 7px; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s; -webkit-transform: scale(.8); -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s; -moz-transform: scale(.8); -ms-transform: scale(.8); transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s; transform: scale(.8); opacity: 0; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ffffff;/*FF 3.5+*/ -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ffffff;/*Saf3-4, Chrome, iOS 4.0.2-4.2, Android 2.3+*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=90, Color=#ffffff)";/*IE 8*/ box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ffffff; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=90, Color=#ffffff);/*IE 5.5-7*/
}

/* Effect */
.stats-box1:hover .stats-effect-inner .stats-effect, .stats-box2:hover .stats-effect-inner .stats-effect, .stats-box3:hover .stats-effect-inner .stats-effect { background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); color: #27CCC0; }

.stats-box1:hover .stats-effect-inner .stats-effect:after, .stats-box2:hover .stats-effect-inner .stats-effect:after, .stats-box3:hover .stats-effect-inner .stats-effect:after { -webkit-transform: scale(1); -moz-transform: scale(1); -ms-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }

/*------------ Icon Hover Effect ------- */

.stats-effect1 > img { padding: 20px; }

.stats-effect-inner1 { position: absolute; right: -33px; top: -33px; }

.stats-effect1 { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%; color: #FF6850; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size: 0; height: 70px; margin: 12px 21px 15px 11px; position: relative; text-align: center; width: 70px; z-index: 1; }

.stats-effect1:after { -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%; content: ""; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; }

.stats-effect1:before { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA; border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%; display: block; font-size: 48px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 90px; text-transform: none; }

.stats-effect-inner1 .stats-effect { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(13, 30, 219, 0.1); transition: background 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s; }
```

TL;DR - I want the icon within the circle in the box to be a normal text number but have the same effect when moused over.

Thanks so much for your help!

EDIT: UPDATED FIDDLE: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CYEa/1)

EDIT: Minimized CSS: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CYEa/2/)

Comment: I see no numbers appearing in your fiddle.

Comment: Still not seeing any numbers in the Fiddle.

Comment: @Æden - the only number that appears in the Result pane is the word 'number' - there are no digits of any description. As a side note, surely the 13 lines of html that the fiddle has don't need 962 lines of css? You may wish to consider trimming the fiddle to a minimal example in the interests of getting better answers. Few people will bother to wade through all of that! (certainly not without money, that is)

Comment: @enhzflep omg! I'm so sorry I didn't even realize I did that. I minimized it all down. :)

The number is "83" in the html. The numbers are not showing in the finished product because it's part of the problem I described in my question.

Comment: @Æden - :grin: easily overlooked. Just a small thing though - the link in this post still points to `jsfiddle.net/5CYEa/1/` and it still has 986 lines of css. No stress, just update your post with the new url (I'm assuming it's an anonymous one, and that you cant change the code that url points to) Thought you may like to know, in case you wondered why answers were a little thin-on-the-ground. :) - I just played with the rule starting on line 952. (.stats-box1:hover etc) I set the line-height and font-size to 80px. It's likely too big, but its a start. http://jsfiddle.net/5CYEa/3/

Comment: @Æden - I've added what I think to be the url of the updated fiddle (/2) apologies if I've been too presumptuous.

Comment: Darn! You messed me up, I added /3 as minimized code although it was /2. Let me remove that real quick.

Comment: What about making it visible before hover? I mean.. I'm completely overlooking something here obviously.

Comment: I made it visible before hover by adding font-size: 50px; to ".stats-effect"

Now I'm having positioning problems, and trying to get it centered is eating me alive. It always moves the circle behind it. :/